# Delete an item from a list by match not index

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],[4,5,6]]
```

I would like to delete an item from this list by matching, not by index. For example, how can I delete `[4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: How is your matching criteria defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `lst.remove(...)`:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"],[4,5,6]]
lst.remove([4,5,6])
print lst
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for such a simple question. I could not find the remove method.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to remove *multiple* occurrences (`lst.remove` will only remove the first match), then it's generally easier to use a list-comp to recreate the list without the elements you want...

```
lst = [el for el in lst if el != [4,5,6]]
```